# Trigger google maps autocomplete on focus out

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**How to reproduce the issue:**

on this page
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

choose some address, for example `20 Water Street, New York City, NY, United States`, (as expected the fields are being filled with the info). Now, e.g. in address change 20 to 10, and  instead of choosing the address from the suggested list, just click somewhere on the page. The suggested list disappears, the new address `10 Water Street, New York City, NY, United States` remains in the input field, but the fields information is not being updated.

I am using this to get the latitude and longitude. So, if the user instead of clicking on the address, clicks outside, it will look like, that he changed the address, but in fact I still will have the previous address's Lat and Lng.

here is the init function

```
var autocomplete;
function initialize() {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('addressAutocomplete')), {
        types : [ 'geocode' ]
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        console.log(place);
    });
}
```

I was thinking smth like this can work, but it does not, this line `console.log(place);` outputs undefined

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('focusout', '#addressAutocomplete', function() {
        google.maps.event.trigger(autocomplete, 'place_changed', {});
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: So you want to auto-select the first suggestion when the input-field loses the focus?

Comment: @Dr.Molle As far as I tried, it looks like yes, but I'm not sure if this will work in all cases. Thanks

Comment: getting response from `var place = autocomplete.getPlace();` check this  http://jsfiddle.net/BBzk6/ ..

Comment: Any update on this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @AlexandreBourlier, unfortunately no...

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452066/google-maps-auto-search-on-page-load

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue (that anything in the given field should be valid Google Maps address), and based on Alexandre Boulier's suggested link built a solution inspired from this one, that may help you. The idea is :

- when the user does something else than click on a Google Maps suggestion
- trigger the event to move focus on the first suggestion
- trigger the event to select it

I copy the result for my own code (with Jquery) :

```
//// Ensuring that only Google Maps adresses are inputted
function selectFirstAddress (input) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(input, 'keydown', {keyCode:40});
    google.maps.event.trigger(input, 'keydown', {keyCode:13});
}

// Select first address on focusout
$('#content').on('focusout', 'input#xxx__zzz', function() {
    selectFirstAddress(this);
});

// Select first address on enter in input
$('#content').on('keydown', 'input#xxx__zzz', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        selectFirstAddress(this);
    }
});
```

For me it works, I hope it helps !